# How to store text checksums for quick binary exists/does-not-exist lookups?

Tags: php, sorting, database-design, solr, datastore

Consider an application which accepts arbitrary-length text input from users, similar to Twitter 'tweets' but up to 1 MiB in size. Due to the distributed nature of the application the same text input may be delivered multiple times to any particular node. In order to prevent the same text from appearing twice in the index (based on Apache Solr), I am using an MD5 hash of the text as a unique key.

Unfortunately, Solr does not support an SQL-like "INSERT IGNORE", as such all duplicate documents ***replace*** the content of the original document. Since the user of the application can add additional fields, this replacement is problematic. In order to prevent it, I have two choices:

1. Before each insert, query the index for documents with the MD5 hashed unique key. If I get a result, then I know that the document already exists in the index. I found this approach to be too slow, probably because we are indexing a few hundred documents per minute.
2. Store the MD5 hash in an additional store, such as a flat file, MySQL, or elsewhere. This approach is the basis of this question.

What forms of data storage can handle a few hundred inserts per minute, and quickly let me know if the value exists? I am testing with both MySQL (on a different spindle than the Solr index) and with flat files using `grep -w someHash hashes.txt` and `cat someHash >> hashes.txt`. Both approaches seem to slow down as the index grows, but it will take a few days or weeks until I see if either approach is feasible.

What other methods of storing and checking the existence of a hash are possible? What fundamental issues might I run into with the MySQL and flat files approach? What would Knuth do?

Answer (score 1):

From solr side, you can try for [Deduplication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) and [UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22) which may serve the purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I have experemented with `overwrite=false` in the past but forgotten about it. It seemed to have some unintuitive side effect / gotcha if I remember right. I'll look into it again and see if this could resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Jayendra. This is a good solution for the specific Solr application. However, I am leaving the question open as in the general sense the question still needs to be addressed!

Comment: Did the overwrite work for you? does it prevent overwriting of the document ?

Comment: No, setting `overwrite=false` has Solr create an additional document, with the same id (which is a uniqueKey). This is not a feasible result.